# Remove index.php of Codeigniter is on a sub-folder on IIS?

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis, url-rewriting

I wanted to have a rewrite rule on our windows server 2012 r2

I have a url like this

```
localhost/mysite1/home
localhost/mysite2/home
```

and its shows `404 page not found`. but when I add `index.php` like this

```
localhost/mysite1/index.php/home
localhost/mysite2/index.php/home
```

it works.

I wanted to remove the `index.php` for my codeigniter site using a rewrite rule.

I already search for the system.webserver answers here in stackoverflow

I came up with this on my `web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <system.webServer>

        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>

        <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="RuleRemoveIndex" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true"/>
            </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>

    </system.webServer>

    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

and it give me a url request like this

```
localhost/index.php/mysite1/home
localhost/index.php/mysite2/home
```

please help.

Sorry for my bad english